# Al subir un proyecto a github solo aparece el readme

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Subi mi proyecto a github y estoy intentando renderizarlo con gh-pages pero solo me aparece mi readme.

Segui la guia https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Mi repositorio es

https://github.com/ericklopez90/landing/tree/gh-pages

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo, puedo acceder a ella, usando este link: https://ericklopez90.github.io/landing/

Comment: Lo solucione utilizando > https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages Y con esto me permitio subirla

Comment: me pasa lo mismo y no pude resolverlo usando esta pagina https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages será que se me está pasando algun paso importante dentro de la terminal?